# Zend Form - How do I remove the optgroup label

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I know this has been asked before, but I just cant seem to find an answer... or solution.

I have many select boxes using 'multiselect'. The dropdowns are being populated from the database, and the first value in the array is always 'Select One'. This I cannot change, I am rewriting an app and am not changing the database at all.

Everything works just fine, but they always come out as 'optgroup' tags with a label, which always puts a '0' at the top of the list. The boxes always say 'Select One', which is great, but when expanded you see the '0' at the top... which is the 'label' attribute to the optgroup tag.

I do it all somehting like this...

```
$Criteria = new Criteria();
$Criteria->add( DictionaryPeer::CATEGORY, 'Progress Notes: Program Status' );
$Criteria->addAscendingOrderByColumn( 'Ordinal' );
$ProgramStatuses = DictionaryPeer::doSelect($Criteria);

$ProgramStatusList = array();
foreach ($ProgramStatuses as $ProgramStatus) {
    $ProgramStatusList [ $ProgramStatus->getDictionaryID() ] = $ProgramStatus->getWord();
}

$form->programstatus->addMultiOptions( array(
$ProgramStatusList ));

echo $form->programstatus->renderLabel() . $form->programstatus->renderViewHelper();
```

I just want to remove the '0' for presentation purposes only...

Any help is always appreciated...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get rid of the OPTGROUP, you just need to **pass a simple array as parameter** to `addMultiOptions()` as follows:

```
$form->programstatus->addMultiOptions($ProgramStatusList);
```

Because if you pass a multidimensional array, Zend_Form will indirectly consider each index of the parent array as a [group of options](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/optgroup#.3Coptgroup.3E) (using the FormElement View Helper).

Comment: That was too simple! Thanks much, now I have a lot of backspacing to do :)